# AdEventListener does not exist in the type StartApp.StartAppWrapper

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting the following error in unity , I tried to refresh the project and to see any suggestion solution but still the same error

> Assets/Plugins/Scripts/AdsManager.cs(10,43): error CS0426: The nested
>   type `AdEventListener' does not exist in the type
>   StartApp.StartAppWrapper

Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using ChartboostSDK;
using System;
using StartApp;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

using SATestAds;

using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using ChartboostSDK;
using System;
using StartApp;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

using SATestAds;

public class AdsManager : StartAppWrapper.AdEventListener
{
    private bool testMode = false;
    private bool loggerEnabled = false;
    private float delay = 0f;
}
```

Comment: What do you do not understand from the error message? There's no `AdEventListener` type from which you want to derive.

Comment: No idea, is StartAppWrapper something you wrote? or an asset you downloaded?

Answer (score 2):

`AdEventListener` is an interface which requires the following conditions be met before you can use it:

**1**.That your Unity version is *Unity 4.2* and above.

**2**.That your current Platform is set to Android. Go to *File* --> *Build Settings...*, select *Android* and click the *Switch Platform* button.  <sup>This is likely the issue.</sup>

Both of these checks are being done with Unity's preprocessor directives such as `UNITY_ANDROID` and `UNITY_4_1`. That interface is only declared when both are true.

Note that this answer assumes that you have already imported the *StartApp-SDK.* If you have not, you can get that [here](https://github.com/StartApp-SDK/StartApp_InApp_SDK_Unity_Example).